# What will be $\sigma (T)$ if $\mathcal H = (0)\ $?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $\mathcal H$ be a complex Hilbert space and $T \in \mathcal L (\mathcal H).$ If $\mathcal H = (0)$ what can we say about $\sigma (T)\ $?

Clearly in this case $T = 0$ and $I = 0.$ So for all $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ we have $T - \lambda I = 0,$ which is trivially invertible in $\mathcal L (\mathcal H) = (0).$ Hence I think $\sigma (T) = \mathbb C.$ But we know that spectrum of a bounded operator is always compact but here we find something non-compact as a spectrum. Doesn't it give us a contradiction?

Comment: You're right up to and including where you say that $T-\lambda I$ is trivially invertible. But that means that $\lambda$ is **not** in the spectrum of $T$. So $\sigma(T)=\varnothing$.

Comment: @Andreas Blass$:$ Yes that's an error. Sorry for that. But we also know that spectrum of a bounded operator over a complex Hilbert space is necessarily non-empty. Am I right? If it is so then again contradiction comes into the picture.

Comment: In most textbooks of functional analysis, the trivial vector space $\{0\}$ is occasionally excluded without mentioning it.